# Automate Already Running Java App By Attaching

Tags: java, ui-automation

There is a java app I use (not mine) and I want to automate it.

I have used autohotkey before to enter text and click buttons but I am not sure how to get text from a java table using it.

What I need is to parse text in a table, process it, enter text (depend on process) and click button. Is there a free automation tool that I can achieve this?

Regards,
Burak

Comment: java Robot class or batch would be worth to look at

Comment: You could try AccViewer just in case it works, it's always the first thing I try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I automate a Java application with AutoHotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17564086/3357935)