# How do I automate a Java application with AutoHotkey?

Tags: java, automation, accessibility, autohotkey

I am using a Java application at work. I need to send clicks to buttons and fill in textboxes. I would like these actions to happen in the background. The [ahk_class](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_class) of the window is SunAwtFrame, and none of the controls are exposed to WindowSpy.

I have used JavaFerret to determine that the first button I want to press has an [AccessibleAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/accessibility/AccessibleAction.html)

```
Version Information:
    Java virtual machine version: 1.7.0_25
    Access Bridge Java class version: 1.7.0_25
    Access Bridge Java DLL version: AccessBridge 2.0.2
    Access Bridge Windows DLL version: AccessBridge 2.0.2

AccessibleContext information:
    Name:  New Call
    Description:  Place a new call
    Role:  push button
    Role in en_US locale:  push button
    States:  enabled,focusable,visible,showing,opaque
    States in en_US locale:  enabled,focusable,visible,showing,opaque
    Index in parent:  1
    Children count:  0
    Bounding rectangle:  [288, 317, 385, 376]
    Top-level window name:  Phone Assistant: 
    Top-level window role:  frame
    Parent name:  
    Parent role:  panel
    Visible descendents count:  0

AccessibleIcons info:
    Number of icons:  1
    Icon 0 description: jar:http://proxy.m5net.com/vox/pa/receptioncenter.jar!/resources/phone.png
    Icon 0 height: 26
    Icon 0 width: 27

AccessibleActions info:
    Number of actions:  1
    Action 0 name: click

Accessible Value information:
    Current Value:  0
    Maximum Value:  1
    Minimum Value:  0
```

The accessibility docs tell me that I should be to tell the object to perform that action, but I don't know how to do this.

Preferably with AutoHotkey, how can this be done?

Comment: I want to use AutoHotKey with a java application as well.  Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I ended up using a hacky solution the AHK script would pull the Java window forward, interact with the inputs and buttons using relative coordinates, and then push the Java window back again.

Comment: If you need to check if a Java app has finished loading, you can try [checking the mouse status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708478/3357935) or the [color of a specific pixel on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23947684/3357935).

Comment: You may be able to use the Java Access Bridge API. (See [How to send to unseen controls in a Java app](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/95343-how-to-send-to-unseen-controls-in-a-java-app/?p=601593))

Comment: You could make it fullscreen, then interact with specific coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the [CoordMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm) to Relative (Or Window which does the same thing), and then you can use [Click](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) or [MouseMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm) with hard-coded pixels relative to the top left corner of the window. You can find the coordinates you need with the Window Spy.

Another option, if you're unsure the hard-coded pixels will be reliable, is you can use the [FindText](https://www.the-automator.com/find-and-click-image-send-text-to-it/) library which allows you to specify what the text/icon is within the window and automate clicks based off of a certain number of pixels nearby that. So for example, if there's always the text "Name:" and an input box to the right of it, you can build a search for "me: [" (left edge of the input box pixels) and then click to the right of that. The library is impressive and uses the built-in [ImageSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) command in AutoHotkey.

The successor of this library is called [AutomateMyTask](https://www.the-automator.com/automatemytask/), which I haven't tried yet, but it claims that you can build your whole click script within a gui that this tool provides. Check it out!